# javascript element.style is undefined in FF

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I want to set up css display property in javascript code:

> ```
>     var div = document.createElement('div');
>     div.innerHTML = content;
>     div.childNodes[0].style.display = '';
> ```

It works in IE but doesn't in FF. It says "style" is undefined for element div.  How can I do it in FF?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of node is `div.childNodes[0]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is `content`? If it starts with white space, then there will be a TextNode as the first child and they don't have style properties (HTMLElementNodes do).

You can either:

- loop over the children until you either get to the end or find an HTMLElementNode
- strip the whitespace from the start of `content`
- switch to using `createElement` and friends instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: Thank you for reply, content is HTML code, but seems it starts with spaces.

Comment: Also, the Element Traversal spec http://www.w3.org/TR/ElementTraversal/ defines properties like `firstElementChild`. I don't know about browser compatibility though

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = content;
div.childElementCount && div.firstElementChild.style.display = '';
```